# How do you left align the text found in a tableView's tableFooterView?

Tags: iphone

I can't see an easy way to do this outside of customizing the actual content.  Tell me I missed something incredibly simple here.

Comment: I think you're thinking of table **section** footers, not the footer for the entire table. A tableFooterView only exists if you've created and assigned a UIView to it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Why not assign the tableFooterView (in your controller) to a UILabel and set the alignment (using the textAlignment method) to left align?

Comment: That certainly is a simple solution but I was hoping that 1) there was an extremely simple way to do this and 2) the label would take on the default style of table footers (will it?).

Comment: The label won't take on the default style of table footers; you'll have to set it up manually. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869344/uitableview-header-footer-font-color) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You call `- (UIView *)tableView:viewForFooterInSection:`. It will return a view, most likely a UILabel and you set the text display using the view's methods.

Comment: This doesn't work. `- (UIView *)tableView:viewForFooterInSection:` is a method of the UITableViewDelegate protocol, and is something you override in order to supply a UIView to be used as a tableView footer. It doesn't return the UIView for an existing tableFooter view. In fact, there's no way to access