# UITableView header/footer font color

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit

When overriding the header/footer of a (group styled) table view, what colour should be used for the header and footer fonts to ensure the header and footer fonts are consistent with the standard header and footer fonts?

*ie* The header is being loaded like this:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        if(myHeaderView == nil) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: @"MyHeaderView"
                                          owner: self
                                        options: nil];
        }
        return myHeaderView;
}
```

Comment: Same question but for iOS 7?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From this [discussion](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1199-default-tableview-section-header-background-color.html)

Here's the `UILabel` info for tableView headers on **iOS 6**:

```
Plain
fontName: Helvetica-Bold
pointSize: 18.000000
textColor: UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 1 1
shadowColor: UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 0.44
shadowOffset: CGSize 0 1


Grouped
fontName: Helvetica-Bold
pointSize: 17.000000
textColor: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.298039 0.337255 0.423529 1
shadowColor: UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 1 1
shadowOffset: CGSize 0 1
```

As for the background of the plain style header, that's a UIImage, not simply a backgroundColor. Notice the subtle vertical gradient.

hope it helps

Comment: For the Grouped tableView footer, everything is the same as the footer except the font is normal weight—not bold—and the point size is 15.

Comment: "As for the background of the plain style header, that's a UIImage, not simply a backgroundColor. Notice the subtle vertical gradient." Actually, all labels have a transparent background colour (full alpha). The gradient comes from the table view's background. There's now even a special "colour" gradient in iOS for the grouped table view. ;-)

Comment: How would I set all of this programatically into my UILabel's Text?

Comment: If you'd rather not type this up yourself, [someone has done so here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12057355/798224).

Comment: The text color components as byte values are 76, 86, 108.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (for the footer), with some fiddling of the CGFrame of the label, and its numberOfLines  it might work for you to:

```
int height = [self tableView:table heightForFooterInSection:section];

UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, table.bounds.size.width - 20, height)] autorelease];
label.text              = [self tableView:table titleForFooterInSection:section];
label.textColor         = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.298 green:0.337 blue:0.423 alpha:1.000];
label.font              = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
label.backgroundColor   = [UIColor clearColor];
label.shadowColor       = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.shadowOffset      = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
label.textAlignment     = UITextAlignmentCenter;
label.numberOfLines     = 2;
```