# UITableViewStyleGrouped default header view?

Tags: uitableview

I'm trying to implement a control for deleting entire sections, and it would look best in my app if the delete button was in the header, as opposed to an overlay like a UIPopoverView.

---

In the process of writing this question, I found the answer. Easy enough, once there's a starting point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got the bulk of the code from [this blog](http://www.randycrafton.com/2010/09/changing-the-text-color-of-a-grouped-uitableviews-section-header/) which has only two posts, both from 2010.
Then I went back to [this site](http://www.gersh.no/posts/view/default_styling_of_sections_headers_in_uitableview_grouped) just for the font color, since it's more trouble to break apart.

Three minor problems, all with the label.

```
- Font is too narrow
- Text color is too dark
- Label origin is wrong
```

The default font is known, so that comes first.

```
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
```

Color is next, since that's easy. Used an image editor's Eyedropper tool for this.

```
label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.298 green:0.337 blue:0.423 alpha:1];
// Is there a difference between alpha:1 and alpha:1.000?
```

Then the hard part. A close guess, and then some tweaking for a perfect match.

```
label.frame = CGRectMake(54, 4, headerView.frame.size.width-20, 22);
```

And now we have a custom implementation that perfectly matches the current Grouped header.

**Finished code:**

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40)];
    tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = headerView.frame.size.height;

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(54, 4, labelSize.width, labelSize.height)];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0]];
    [label setShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [label setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
    [label setText:[self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section]];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.298 green:0.337 blue:0.423 alpha:1.000]];
    [headerView addSubview:label];

    return headerView;
}
```

Found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869344/uitableview-header-footer-font-color/5869424#5869424) after finding the right font/color myself. Oh well.

**Edit:**

For a title label that allows an effectively unlimited amount of text:

```
// before label init
NSString *title = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
NSUInteger maxWidth = headerView.frame.size.width-108;
CGSize labelSize = [title sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0]
                     constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(maxWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
if (labelSize.width < maxWidth) labelSize.width = maxWidth;

// after setFont:
[label setNumberOfLines:0];
```

Comment: I believe there should be a [label release] and [headerView autorelease] unless ARC is being used.

Comment: Please do not edit my pixel-perfect custom header in a way that breaks it. // Also, I noticed that, while the default header can handle excessive title lengths (it wraps to a second line), this example does not display more than one line of text, although the header view's height does increase. Fixing this bug would be much appreciated.